# SQL - Summing from two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying to sum up the vales in two different attributes in two different tables and having problem doing it. So my tables structure is:

**Position**

- positionID (PK)
- type

**StaffRequest**

- requestID (PK)
- positionID (FK from Position)

**Recruitment**

- recruitmentID(PK)
- requestID (FK from StaffRequest)

**RegularRecruitment**

- recruitmentID(PK, FK from Recruitment)
- numberOfWeeks

**RegRecruitWeeklyTime**

- ID (PK)
- recruitmentID(FK from RegularRecruitment)
- hours

So, those 5 tables are related to the query I'm trying to perform. `RegRecruitWeeklyTime` table will contain all the weekly time of the regular staff and summing the hours for the particular `recruitmentID` would give us the total number of hours a week that recruit is going to work. And the `numberOfWeeks` table would give you the number of hours the recruit is suppose to work.

Now I want to write a query that will give me total number of hours and total number of weeks, and group them up by their position type. This has to be done in single query.

So, at first I wrote two queries to perform each summing.

```
SELECT
  Position.type AS 'Position',
  SUM(RegularRecuitment.numberOfWeeks) AS 'Total Weeks'
FROM Position, StaffRequest, Recruitment, RegularRecuitment
WHERE 
  Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID 
  AND
  StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
  AND
  Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
GROUP BY Position.type;
```

And

```
SELECT 
  Position.type AS 'Position',
  SUM(RegRecruitWeeklyTime.hours) AS 'Total hours'
FROM Position, StaffRequest, Recruitment, RegularRecuitment, RegRecruitWeeklyTime
WHERE
  RegRecruitWeeklyTime.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID
  AND
  Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID 
  AND
  StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
  AND
  Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
GROUP BY Position.type;
```

If I run those two queries separately, it works fine and gives me correct result. However, when I combined those 2 queries like this:

```
SELECT 
  Position.type AS 'Position', 
  SUM(RegRecruitWeeklyTime.hours) AS 'Total hours each week',
  SUM(RegularRecuitment.numberOfWeeks) AS 'Total Weeks'
FROM Position, StaffRequest, Recruitment, RegRecruitWeeklyTime, RegularRecuitment
WHERE
  RegRecruitWeeklyTime.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID
  AND
  Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID 
  AND
  StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
  AND
  Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
GROUP BY Position.type;
```

The `'Total Weeks'` column is multiplied by the number of rows in `RegRecruitWeeklyTime`, meaning the result is `SUM(RegularRecuitment.numberOfWeeks) * COUNT(RegRecruitWeeklyTime.hours)`. If I divide the 'Total Weeks' column value by `COUNT(RegRecruitWeeklyTime.hours)`, I get the right answer but I just wanted to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is to find `'Total hours'` `RegRecruitWeeklyTime` table  is joined with `RegularRecuitment` to get the result but to find `'Total Weeks'` you were not joining `RegRecruitWeeklyTime` table so. when you try to combine the queries obviously the `'total weeks'` will differ.Try this..

```
SELECT A.Position,
       A.Total_Weeks,
       A.Total_hours
FROM   (SELECT Position.type                        AS 'Position',
               Sum(RegularRecuitment.numberOfWeeks) AS 'Total_Weeks'
        FROM   Position
               JOIN StaffRequest
                 ON Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
               JOIN Recruitment
                 ON StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
               JOIN RegularRecuitment
                 ON Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID
        GROUP  BY Position.type) a
       JOIN (SELECT Position.type                   AS 'Position',
                    Sum(RegRecruitWeeklyTime.hours) AS 'Total_hours'
             FROM   Position
                    JOIN StaffRequest
                      ON Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
                    JOIN Recruitment
                      ON StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
                    JOIN RegularRecuitment
                      ON Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID
                    JOIN RegRecruitWeeklyTime
                      ON RegRecruitWeeklyTime.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID
             GROUP  BY Position.type) b
         ON A.Position = B.Position
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using what database??

if you are using sqlserver

you can always do this

```
SELECT 
(
  SELECT
    Position.type AS 'Position',
    SUM(RegularRecuitment.numberOfWeeks) AS 'Total Weeks'
  FROM Position, StaffRequest, Recruitment, RegularRecuitment
  WHERE
    Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID 
    AND
    StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
    AND
    Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
  GROUP BY Position.type
) AS select1,

(
  SELECT
    Position.type AS 'Position',
    SUM(RegRecruitWeeklyTime.hours) AS 'Total hours'
  FROM Position, StaffRequest, Recruitment, RegularRecuitment, RegRecruitWeeklyTime
  WHERE
    RegRecruitWeeklyTime.recruitmentID=RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID
    AND
    Recruitment.recruitmentID = RegularRecuitment.recruitmentID 
    AND
    StaffRequest.requestID = Recruitment.requestID
    AND
    Position.positionID = StaffRequest.positionID
  GROUP BY Position.type
) AS select2
```